# Should I use separate log files or log everything to the journal?

Tags: logs, systemd-journald

On my personal server I currently have multiple services (web server, mail server, etc) and some of them have their own log files while others log everything to stdout and that gets picked up by the systemd journal.

That means I have separate log files for some services, while others are in the journal; I feel that's inconsistent and I'd like to log everything in the journal so I have only one place to check for logs.

Is that a good idea ? I'm worried some high traffic services (web server) may overload the journal; I'm not sure how resource-hungry logging to the journal is compared to a basic text file.

Comment: I can't write a comprehensive answer (especially regarding resource usage, which I don't know how to answer) but changing where you store the log is going to change how it's represented which can break analytics software. For example, you can pipe apache logs to `syslog` but the timestamp/program/tag/etc that syslog adds will make the resulting log indecipherable to programs like webalizer. I would imagine the same would be true of `journald` as well.

Comment: You may consider only piping errors to `journald` though. By definition that's (hopefully) a lot more low-flow and if you're needing apache access logs to solve some problem, you're probably already neck-deep in Apache-specific stuff already.

Comment: @Bratchley thanks for your reply; I don't really care about analytics and a high flow isn't a problem for me (but it may be in terms of resources, that's why I'm asking), the journalctl command has sorting functions to deal with that.

Comment: @Bratchley you can configure `journald` to log the journal and also forward to `syslog`

Comment: @jordanm right I'm aware it's possible, I'm just saying I don't have the information required to make an informed statement about how much overhead is involved by introducing `journald` which is the main part of the OP's question.

Comment: About the overload worry - you can configure a message frequency backoff - and i think it institutes some presumed sane default already anyway. Never used this for anything, just recall reading it once in `man`. You should look through that - and the series 5 entry for its conf file.